# Calculating the work indices of a bitonic sort

Tags: algorithms

I have worker units that take the input of A and B. Using that they do the comparison of A > B and if true, they swap the values of A and B. This requires me to give the orders to each of the worker threads which I calculate in a sequential function following the example of other implementations.

I could increase the efficiency of the algorithm if I could figure out A and B inside the worker as a function of unique worker ID(0, 1, 2 .. N - 1) and the current step(1, 2, 4, 8 .. N) where N is length of the input sequence / 2. Keeping the previous A and B is also an option.

Heres a picture I found illustrating the concept: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hvWzQ42RXAw/UgPfdkYXraI/AAAAAAAAABo/BWsKEHQl8KE/s1600/bitonic.png

I'm interested in the leftmost half of the process, mainly the first comparisons of the blocks so (on that picture) A, B, D and G which would correspond to step value of 1, 2, 4, 8.

The worker units can jump around however much they like and whcih of the pair is A and which is B doesn't matter(since its easy to determine that) so for example worker ID = 0 could go (A, B) [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 4] [0, 8] or it could be [0, 1] [1, 3] [2, 6] [7, 3] or whatever.

I tried charting out various combinations of possible sequences but couldn't find an universal pattern that wasn't recalculating the entire work order list in the same way as I do in the sequential function (which is based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter#Example_code mine is a bit different because it calculates the sequence before dispatching it to the workers all at the same time per each step but that one is easier to read and less cluttered with irrelevant things).

So, would it be possible to work out the A and B based on a unique identifier and information on which step of the process is currently occurring?

Comment: When I stopped staring at the pictures and started thinking, turns out it was rather simple A = floor(id / step) * step * 2 + (id % step). I also worked out the positive/negative boxes and the merge transitions separately by the same input. They have a lot of the same operations along the way so lots of optimizations to do!

Comment: couldn't resist making a picture http://i.imgur.com/YrXwRUU.png its the most beautiful thing ive seen all day